# Unknown mathematical series in C

Tags: c, math, numbers, series

Does anybody have any idea what this code does? I suspect it has something to do with Taylor series, but I'm not sure since I don't really know what Taylor series is. However, it could be anything. I'm really not sure.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int main() {
  double x, y, a;
  int n;
  int z;
  x = 25.0;
  if (z < 0) {
    z = 1;
    x = -x;
  } else
    z = 0;
  n = 0;
  a = 1;
  y = 1;
  for (n = n + 1; n < 20; n++) {
    a = a * x / n;
    y = y + a;
    printf("%i \t %.20g \t %g \n", n, y, a);
  }
  if (z) {
    x = -x;
    y = 1.0 / y;
  }
  printf("%i \t %.20g \t %g \n", n, y, a);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do not put more than one statement on one line. Keep your code nicely formatted, respect your readers.

Comment: `z` is uninitialized, everything that follows from `if(z<0)` yields undefined behaviour, so it is meaningless.

Comment: Yes, I already edited it. It was just copy-pasted and I'm really not a C programmer, so I didn't notice.

Comment: Though it does produce some numbers, and those are important for me to understand what they mean.

Comment: @Wranny did you updated the code in your answer? If so, still wrong, `z` is still uninitialized before the `if(z < 0)` line. The result will be undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Enable compiler warnings.

`if (z < 0) {` is a coding error.  [@Pablo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48738275/unknown-mathematical-series-in-c#comment84476297_48738275).

It certainly should be

```
if (x < 0) {
```

---

Unrolling

```
  n = 0;
  a = 1;
  y = 1;
  for (n = n + 1; n < 20; n++) {
    a = a * x / n;
    y = y + a;
```

The terms are

```
  y = 1 + x/1 + x*x/(1*2) + x*x*x/(1*2*3) + ....  pow(x,20)/(1*2*3*...*20)
```

Review [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) to discern which one.

---

BTW, For `x==25`, code Taylor's series does not converge enough.  Either more terms are needed or better - an alternate/additional approach is needed.

Comment: That'n there looks like that ole `e^x` ifn I recall my cypherin.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Better to let OP find it.